# Why is Android allocating twice as much memory as I expect for an image?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I'm loading an image resource in an Android application using setImageResource(), and for some reason this is using a lot of extra memory.

This is what I see when the image is loaded:

```
03-29 15:16:56.687: D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 11% free 16175K/18119K, paused 11ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(23616): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.154MB for 7675216-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 8% free 23667K/25671K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 23667K/25671K, paused 10ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(23616): Grow heap (frag case) to 39.624MB for 17272816-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 40535K/42567K, paused 1ms+2ms
```

The jpg is 1599x1200, so I would expect the first allocation - 1599 * 1200 * 4 = 7675200.
What's going on with the 17MB allocation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is most likely you put your image into `drawable-mdpi` or just `drawable` directory, but run the app on the `hdpi` device. In this case image's dimensions will be scaled by 1.5.

```
1599 * 1200 * 4 * 1.5 * 1.5 = 17269200b ~ 17mb
```

You should probably move the image to `drawable-nodpi` directory to avoid unwanted scale.